# How to cast the inherited Object injava

Tags: java, spring-boot

I face a small problem when receiving inherited Object in java Spring boot.

```
class AbstractEntity{
    String type;
    Integer age;
}

class Animal extends AbstractEntity{
    String legs;
}

class Bird extends AbstractEntity{
    String flySpeed;
}

class Human extends AbstractEntity{
    String firstname;
    String lastname;
}
```

`Human`, `Bird` and `Animal` are inherited from `AbstractEntity`. Now Im receiving a Human Object from front end. I need to identify the object from `type`

```
{
    type: "Human",
    age:30;
    firstname:"John",
    lastname: "Smith"
}
```

Currently I'm using map to identify

```
public void save(@RequestBody Map entity){
    
    if(entity.get("type").equalsIgnoreCase("Human")){
        Human h=new Human(entity.get("type"),entity.get("age"),entity.get("firstname"),entity.get("lastname"))
    }
    // same for Animal and bird
}
```

I can't specify the object without knowing the type in controller. If I receive the Object using `AbstractEntity` like `@RequestBody AbstractEntity entity` then children fields will be missing. Is there any easy and better approach rather than using `Map`?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you to explore the Jackson annotations `@JsonTypeInfo`, `@JsonSubTypes` and `@JsonTypeName`.

It would be something similar to:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,
              include = As.PROPERTY, property = "type")
@JsonSubTypes({
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Animal.class, name = "animal"),
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Bird.class, name = "bird"),
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Human.class, name = "human")
})
class AbstractEntity {
}

@JsonTypeName("animal")
class Animal extends AbstractEntity {
}

@JsonTypeName("bird")
class Bird extends AbstractEntity {
}

@JsonTypeName("human")
class Human extends AbstractEntity {
}
```

This is just a basic example, there are other approaches with the same annotations you can take without defining the `@JsonTypeName` if I don't recall wrongly.